# Where's dist() method located

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to understand gradle distribution. In the **[gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N10568)**, section 7.3.4, there's the following code example:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn spiJar
    from 'src/dist'
    into('libs') {
        from spiJar.archivePath
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}
```

I was trying to find method `dist()` to understand what exact it does. I was searching for in [org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html) but there is no such method. So where is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could You please provide a link to the example You mentioned?

It seems that `dist()` method is defined nowhere. The code sample You provided is just a task definition so in this particular case `dist` is just a name of the defined task of type `Zip`. `from` and `into` methods are taken from [AbstractCopyTask](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html).

**EDIT**

So, as stated above `dist()` is just an ordinary task definition, while for instance the next  piece of code in the example:

```
artifacts {
   archives dist
}
```

has a dedicated method defined in [AbstractProject](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/project/AbstractProject.java) class:

```
public void artifacts(Closure configureClosure) {
   ConfigureUtil.configure(configureClosure, getArtifacts());
}
```

Now, why this error:

```
Could not find method dist() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip}, txt, build_275gv6pdo8dsig251h253koq9t$_run_closure2@a81512] on proj ect ':MP'.
```

occurs for this input:

```
task dist(type: Zip, 'txt')
```

?

During script parsing (which is a dynamic and quite complicated process) the declaration above should be turned into invocation of one of `create` methods on [TaskContainer](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html) instance, where *dist* is a task name of type `String` and `type: Zip, 'txt'` should be passed as arguments. As You can see in the docs for [TaskContainer](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html) there's no `create` method that takes `String` (*dist* - task name), then `Map` (*type: Zip* - task config), and again a String (*txt* - redundant/invalid argument). That's why it's failing.

If You're interested how it works, it's good idea to put the following piece of code in build.gradle:

```
task someTask {
   throw new RuntimeException()
}
```

and investigate the stacktrace. It will tell You a lot about how it works step by step.

Comment: Sure, I've added a reference. Why when I replace `task dist(type: Zip)` to, say, `task dist(type: Zip, 'txt')` I'll get an error _> Could not find method dist() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip}, txt, build_275gv6pdo8dsig251h253koq9t$_run_closure2@a81512] on proj
ect ':MP'._ Looks like it has to be exist some method called `dist()`. could you clarify that moment?

Answer (score 2):

There is no dist method. In this example, you are using the gradle dsl to create a new task called "dist" whose type is "Zip".

This is accomplished through the use of "method missing".  See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing for more info.

Note: if you change "dist" to "foo", this is still a valid example, but with a less self-explanatory task name.